# jQuery SyntaxError: missing : after property id, when get hidden inputs .val()

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to grab a the value attribute from a hidden input field, below is my hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="cat_id" value="<?=$category->cat_id;?>" />
```

Here is the jQuery to grab the value:

```
var catId = jQuery("#cat_id").val();
```

Pretty straight forward huh? But I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

Any Google search or on here is bringing up results relating to objects, but I am not using any objects here...

The whole code is huge but it will be here for sure:

```
    <?php if($option->image_path){ ?>

         <?php
         $imgpath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-content/plugins/metal-work/gates/".$option->image_path;

          $img = new Imagick($imgpath);
          $img->trimImage(0);

          ?>

          <input id="img<?=$option->step_id; ?>" type="hidden" name="img<?=$option->step_id;?>" value="<?=$img; ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" id="cat_id" value="<?=$category->cat_id;?>" />
          <input type="hidden" id="step_id" value="<?=$option->step_id;?>" />
          <input type="hidden" id="action" value="imgPost" />

          <script>

          var catId = jQuery("#cat_id").val();
          var stepId = jQuery("#step_id").val();
          var img = jQuery("img"+stepId).val();
          var imgPost = jQuery("#action").val();

          jQuery.ajax({

                   type: "POST",

                   url: "/wp-content/plugins/metal-work/ajax-imagemagick.php",

                   data: { 'catId':catId, 'stepId':stepId, img:'img', 'imgPost':imgPost },

                        success:function (data){
                              if(data == 'ok'){
                                 alert('success');
                               } else {
                                    alert('Oops something went wrong loading the image.');
                               }

                          },

                       });
                       </script>

                       <label for="step<?=$i;?>-<?=$option->id;?>"><?php echo $img; ?></label><br/>

                  <?php } ?>
```

Regards
Rick

Comment: The error is not in the code that you posted. There should be a line together with the error, try checking the code there?

Comment: could you post your full code? the error isn't here

Comment: its on the 6th line -> SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Comment: correct sir! Thanks that solved it! I have edited the code above!

Comment: You shouldn't edit the code in your question because then it isn't clear anymore what the problem was.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put `var` declarations inside an object literal. Move all of them above the function call:

```
var catId = jQuery("#cat_id").val();
// ...

jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  // ...
});
```

> Any Google search or on here is bringing up results relating to objects, but I am not using any objects here...

Yes you are. The value you are passing to `.ajax()` is an object and you use an object literal to create it. See [**MDN - Working with Objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).